# Xcode 4.1 - Archiving app gives me Entitlments.plist error

Tags: xcode4, archive, code-signing, osx-lion

I am using Xcode 4.1 and MacOSX Lion 10.7. I am trying to archive my Mac app so I can upload my app to iTunes connect but it gives me this error:

ProcessProductPackaging /Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Entitlements.plist /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname/Build/Intermediates/appname.build/Debug/appname.build/appname.xcent
    cd "/Volumes/Apps/iOS/Mac app store/appname"
    builtin-productPackagingUtility /Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Entitlements.plist -entitlements -format xml -o /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname/Build/Intermediates/appname.build/Debug/appname.build/appname.xcent

error: error reading property list '/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Entitlements.plist' - property list has no object
Command builtin-productPackagingUtility failed with exit code 1

This error does not occur if I don't sign the code. I was able to submit my apps properly before upgrading to Xcode 4.1. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to sign an app in xcode 4 and I have no idea what the new Enable entitlements and sandbox does.

When I somehow get it to work, I get this email from iTunes connect with the following error:
Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile:

According to the provisioning profile, the bundle contains a key value that is not allowed: "appname" for the key "com.apple.application-identifier" in appname.app/Contents/MacOS/appname

What do I need to do to properly submit my app to iTunes connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, there is an issue with packaging apps if you are using a new Macbook manufactured after June of 2010. To package your app, follow these steps:

1) Build and Archive

2) Open the Organizer - Archives, find the new archive.

3) Right-click the archive "Show in Finder"

4) Right-click the archive in the finder to "Show Package Contents"

5) drill down to your app (>Products/Applications/YourApp)

6) Right-click your app, "Show Package Contents"

7) Delete the _CodeSignature directory

8) Edit Info.plist

```
 a) Change BuildMachineOSBuild to "11A511"

 b) Save, close
```

9) Go back to the Products/Applications/YourApp directory in the finder

10) Open Keychain Access.app

```
 a) Find your certificate "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Your Name"

 b) double click to inspect it

 c) Copy the full Common Name "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Your Name"
```

11) Open a terminal and enter the following:

```
 codesign -s "<paste your cert common name here>" -fv <drag the archived app from the finder to the terminal window here>
```

12) verify the output:

```
 "...path to app...: replacing invalid existing signature"

 "...path to app...: signed bundle with Mach-O universal (i386 x86_64)"
```

13) Close all them windows.

14) Open the Organizer - Archives in XCode

15) Validate... yep.

16) Submit... yay!

Comment: encoutering this as well, many thanks, +1. Did you by any chance find what's actually causing this codesign error ?

Answer (score 0):

This method actually worked for me too!

This was my error, iTunes Connect kept kicking it out, not rejecting...just almost instant kick-out.
So anyway...this method worked for me!  now app is sitting In Review.  As he said Yay!

---

Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on Mac OS X; 
this may happen if your Mac OS X project was ported from iOS. 
Please check your Xcode project's code signing entitlements configuration, and remove any unneeded entitlements.

Specifically, key "keychain-access-groups" in [YourAppName] is not supported. 
Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on Mac OS X; 
this may happen if your Mac OS X project was ported from iOS. 
Please check your Xcode project's code signing entitlements configuration, and remove any unneeded entitlements. 
Specifically, key "application-identifier" in [YourAppName] is not supported.

---

Just want to add in there...that I also had a black MacBook, that was manufactured BEFORE 2010...I still went ahead and added the key "BuildMachineOSBuild to "11A511" like the instructions said.  :)